# IOS/Addressbook framework: 2nd street address field in contact

Tags: ios, addressbook, multivalue

In the Apple contacts app, when you go to edit a contact, there are two fields labeled Street.

I am able to pull in the information from the first field with the following code:

```
ABMultiValueRef st = ABRecordCopyValue(addressBookRecord, kABPersonAddressProperty);
        if (ABMultiValueGetCount(st) > 0) {
            CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(st, 0);
            self.addr1 = (__bridge NSString *)(CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey));
        }
```

Can anyone tell me how to pull the info from the second field or otherwise shed light on what it is?  There does not seem to be a specific key for it as there is for the first address field, city, state and zip

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

For adding you can use:

```
[addressDictionary setObject:@"Street 1\nStreet 2" forKey:(NSString *)kABPersonAddressStreetKey];
```

For retrieving you can just:

```
NSString *street = [(NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey) copy];
```

This will give you the `Street 1` and `Street 2` strings